# Visual Studio 2015 Separate Zoom Levels

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In `Visual Studio 2015` all the `Zoom Levels` are synced together when I am coding.

This is great when working on the same monitor, however when I have a higher resolution monitor and my laptop monitor then this is rather annoying as the zoom levels make the text look alright on one monitor, but too large on another monitor.

Is there any way of turning off the `Zoom Level` syncing?, so I can select my zoom level per code window?

Comment: I really hope someone finds an answer to this because I'm having the same issue. 2013 had this feature and I've gotten used to it for the exact same reason that you mentioned above.

Comment: Incredibly annoying, isn't it! Maybe we can get some more people to support bringing back this feature by voting here: [visual studio user forum to bring back individual zoom levels](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/10994709-bring-back-individual-zoom-levels-for-each-window)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not quite what you are looking for, but you can make windows do the scaling for you. By setting different scaling levels on the two monitors (only works with Windows 8.1), you don't even have to manually adjust the code zooming (another upside of this is that not only the code becomes readable, but the UI is scaled, too).

Comment: how does that behave if i put the window in the middle spanning both screens?

Comment: Horrible as you might expect.